# cannot delete (rm) a file in c program but can in shell

Tags: c, linux, rm

My C program (on Linux) needs to delete a file, say, /home/me/myfile, here is how I do it in my program

```
...
system ("rm -f /home/me/myfile");
...
```

When running this program, I got a message saying permission denied. BTW, `ls -al /home/me/myfile` returns `-rw-r--r--`

However, under the same user account and in the same shell I execute the C program, I can simple delete the file by typing `rm -f /home/me/myfile`

What did I miss here?

Thanks,

Update: Using `remove(/home/me/myfile)` or `unlink(/home/me/myfile)`, the file can be deleted in my program.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use the `unlink` function call and get a better error value?

Comment: use `unlink("/home/me/myfile");`

Comment: This is likely because (a) you need to specify the full path of /bin/rm, (b) calling system, you are throwing away any diagnostic output generated, and (c) you ignore the system return code.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham and that should be your answer.

Comment: If youre running from the console, then run the output file with **sudo**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, it's the permissions on the *directory* that control whether you can delete a file.

But, having said that, there are numerous things that could be different between the two situations. Your program might be running as a different user (such as with the SETUID bit), the path may be different, leading to a different `rm` being run, the program may set up a `chroot` jail so that it can no longer even see the file (though that may manifest as a *different* error), and so forth. The possibilities are rather large.

However, C provides a call to delete files, called `unlink` - you should use that in preference and then check `errno`.

I would suggest checking the output of `which rm` in both cases, along with the full details of the file and executable, owner and permissions.

Comment: Thanks for @paxdiablo's suggestion. With `remove()` or `unlink()`, the problem does go away. But I dont understand "Your program might be running as a different user (such as with the SETUID bit), the path may be different, leading to a different rm being run, the program may set up a chroot jail so that it can no longer even see the file (though that may manifest as a different error), and so forth." My program is very simple, like main(){system("rm -f /home/me/myfile");}, how could those things happen?